# How to get a form in jquery submit callback

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to get a `form` from the `submit callback` provided by jQuery, because i have n forms on a single page, with a commun class `many` and a `data-id` attribute attached to each form.

I need to get back this `data-id` and the inputs of the `form` in this callback, i can't otherwise since they just have a cummon class.

I am looking for something like that:

```
$('form.many').submit(function(e) {
        console.log($(this).data('id')); //Desn't work
        console.log($(this).serializeArray()); //Desn't work
        return false;
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="many" data-id="1">
  <textarea>TEST_1</textarea>
</form>

<form class="many" data-id="2">
  <textarea>TEST_2</textarea>
</form>

//...
```

I get `[]` for the `$(this).serializeArray();` How to get the textarea content ?

Comment: Could you show us the HTML? This might work...

Comment: Doesn't look like an issue, there muct be something else going wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/EZQFc/

Comment: Hi Ludo, I am not sure whether this is possible with $.submit. You may want to try to do the post using $.ajax, where there is a very clean way of capturing the results via callback

Comment: can you add a `console.log(this)` and see what is `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look of this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/6CvU7/ 
i think you have a mistake in your html code i make a fiddle and it will work fine

```
<form>
<div><input type="text" name="a" value="1" id="a" /></div>
<div><input type="text" name="b" value="2" id="b" /></div>
<div><input type="hidden" name="c" value="3" id="c" /></div>
<div>
<textarea name="d" rows="8" cols="40">4</textarea>
</div>
<div><select name="e">
<option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
</select></div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="f" value="8" id="f" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="g" value="Submit" id="g" />
</div>
</form>

$('form').submit(function() {
console.log($(this).serializeArray());
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.many').submit(function(e) {
        console.log($(this).data('id')); //Desn't work, 
        //if data is defined then it will work 
        // or use attr if you have given id to your from element
        console.log($(this).serializeArray()); //Desn't work
        return false;
    });
});
```

You must check that your page having **HTML** like

```
<form class="many" action="" data-id="frmUpdate">

</form>
```

Also Check that you include the `jQuery` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

does this help at all?

```
var data = {};
$.each($('form.many').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
   data[field.name] = field.value;
});
```